# Why is my WPF CompboBox Empty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I know this is a common question, but as far as I can see from other posts, I am doing everything right ... obviously I'm not.

My C# in the code behind

```
        InitializeComponent();
        cboCustomerIds.DataContext = new Customers();
```

My C# in the business objects tier

```
namespace BusinessObjects
{
public class Customers
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public Int64 CustomerId { get; set; }
    }

    public List<int> CustomerIds { get; set; }

    public Customers()
    {
        DataLayer dl = new DataLayer();
        SqlDataReader reader = dl.GetSqlDataReader("GetCustomerIds");
        List<Int64> CustomerIds = new List<Int64>();
        try
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                do
                {
                    Int64 thing = 0;
                    thing = (Int64)reader["CustomerId"];
                    CustomerIds.Add(thing);
                    int count = CustomerIds.Count;
                    Int64 id = CustomerIds[count-1];
                }
                while (reader.Read());
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

The C# does a count of CustomerIds so I can bebug and confirm items are being returned from the database and added to the list.
My XAML

```
    <Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cboCustomerIds" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerIds}" DisplayMemberPath="CustomerId" Width="120">
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

It builds without error and runs. It invokes the Customers constructor and builds the list of CustomerIds, but cboCustomerIds displays an empty list.

Comment: Try removing the `DisplayMemberPath` attribute on the ComboBox.

Comment: Thank you @Gjeltema but I only added DisplayMemberPath after it didn't work without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your code carefully, these code are never be referenced.

```
    public class Customer
    {
        public Int64 CustomerId { get; set; }
    }

    public List<int> CustomerIds { get; set; }
```

You read data from DB and add them into

`List<Int64> CustomerIds = new List<Int64>();`

not into

`public List<int> CustomerIds { get; set; }`

but the ComboBox binding with `public List<int> CustomerIds { get; set; }`

so everything looks strange.

Here is an example:

```
 public class Customers
{


    public List<int> CustomerIds { get; set; }

    public Customers()
    {

        CustomerIds = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            CustomerIds.Add(i);
        }
    }


}
```

and you should remove DisplayMemberPath at first.

I guess your demand is :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cboCustomerIds.DataContext = new Customers();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// ViewModel
/// </summary>
public class Customers
{
    public List<Customer> LstCustomer { get; set; }

    public Customers()
    {
        LstCustomer = new List<Customer>();

        //get data from DB, here is an example
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Customer c = new Customer();
            c.CustomerId = i;
            c.CustomerName = "name" + i;
            c.CustomerAge = 10 + i;

            LstCustomer.Add(c);
        }
    }


}

/// <summary>
/// Model
/// </summary>
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public int CustomerAge { get; set; }
}
```

and the `View`:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="cboCustomerIds" ItemsSource="{Binding LstCustomer}" DisplayMemberPath="CustomerId" />
```

Comment: Thank you @Rang. This solution worked once I referenced the list correctly.